# Centos 7 RHSA-2019:0201 - Security update rpm

Tags: centos

An update for systemd package released for Redhat Enterprise Linux. Is this rpm update avilable to Centos 7 OS?

Centos Required this rpm systemd-219-62.el7_6.3.x86_64.rpm.

Link:

https://dl.packetstormsecurity.net/1901-advisories/RHSA-2019-0201-01.txt

Thanks

Comment: From what I was able to find, this change has not been updated for CentOS yet. Given that the advisory was only issued yesterday and that it is a 'low' impact problem, the fixes may be delivered to CentOS in a few days. You should be able to search for CESA 2019:0201 to look for the announcement.

Comment: Monitor the CentOS-announce mailing list for updates. https://lists.centos.org/mailman/listinfo/centos-announce

Comment: I see the fix for centos 7 now.

Answer (score 0):

As jsbillings said, I see the fix here. https://lists.centos.org/pipermail/centos-announce/2019-February/023163.html